# Programmatically create table with clickable and expandable content in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This is what I desire to create:

[image]

As you see I need to create table like control with images and clickable cells. When you click on an arrow on the left it expands its' content and content contains some more additional table like controls with data. Also when user clicks on a Star I need to add this event to Favorites list and etc.

Currently, for each data row I'm thinking of programmatically creating accordion item with Grid in header for images and cells and other Grids for the content.

What is the best and easier way to achieve this task? What controls should I use? I need some suggestions, as I'm new to WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF DataGrid can show RowDetails. Customize them with [RowDetailsTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowdetailstemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) property and manage their visibility with [RowDetailsVisibilityMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowdetailsvisibilitymode(v=vs.110).aspx) property

Comment: Can I make in code behind with C#? For example, for each datarow that I have?

Comment: @ITCaptain, there is always c# equivalent for xaml markup, so yes, it is possible